# MongoDB Collation loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to run a find inside another find and I am not getting any results from the second find operation.

```
User.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    for (i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        var tmp = '';

        UserGroups.find({userName: docs[i].userName}, function (errin, groups) {
            for (g = 0; g < groups.length; g++) {
                tmp += ", " + groups[g].groupName;
                //console.log(groups[g].groupName);
            }
        });

        console.log(tmp);

        //docs[i].group = that;
        docs[i].username = decrypt(docs[i].username);
        docs[i].password = '';

    }
    res.render('users', {users: docs});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserGroups.find` is going to be run asynchronously therefore  `console.log(tmp)` is going to be run before your `UserGroups.find` has a chance to finish and your call is going to return before you get any results. If you want the results of the `UserGroup.find` you need to move all of your logic into that callback.

**EDIT**

This is I believe a far better approach in terms of predictability and query performance. Your previous approach the `UserGroup.find` being called n number of times. N being the number of users in your database. This approach the database is only queried twice. Once to get all the users and second to get all the groups.

```
User.find({}, function (err, docs) {

    //Get all the usernames before executing the UserGroups query
    var userNames = [];
    users.forEach(function(element) {
        userNames.push(element.userName);
    });

    UserGroups.find({userName: {$in : userNames}}, function (errin, groups) {
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
            //get all the groups that belong to this user
            var userGroups = groups.filter(function(value) {
                return value.userName === docs[i].userName;
            });

            var tmp = "";
            userGroups.forEach(function(element){
                tmp += "," + element.groupName
            });

            //docs[i].group = that;
            docs[i].username = decrypt(user[i].username);
            docs[i].password = '';
        }
        res.render('users', {users: docs});
    });
});
```

Also since it appears you are using Mongoose you can use the built in [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) feature  in Mongoose to "join" collections together

Comment: For populate? Have you read the documentation? I doubt it since I posted it 15 seconds ago. Try to make it work first then if you have difficulties post another question.

Comment: the code that was executing after the UserGroups.find() is now within the UserGroups.find() callback. notice where the console.log and docs[i] code is now located in my answer

Comment: Oh ok I think I got it... I'll check it tomorrow on pc . Thanks man

Comment: There is still an issue with my answer however you may not get the last Users groups in the query because of an issue with the first for loop finishing before the last UserGroups.find() call back can be evaluated. your best option here is to look into using Mongoose populate if you have control of the models. otherwise your code needs some rework to prevent the issue I mentioned